# Avoid using duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom *React Table component* that is part of ui-library.

```js
const Table = ({tableId, ...props}) => {
  // do something with tableId

  // render ui
}
```

This component gets `tableId` as a prop. I want to avoid duplicating this prop.
It should be impossible to use the same tableId values for two different tables:

```js
// Wrong!
const Table1 = () => <Table tableId="not_uniq_key"/>
const Table2 = () => <Table tableId="not_uniq_key"/>

// Correct!
const Table1 = () => <Table tableId="uniq_key"/>
const Table2 = () => <Table tableId="another_uniq_key"/>
```

My question is: how is this possible, and if possible, what is the best approach to achieve it?

My thoughts are as follows:

1. Eslint rule. Unfortunately, I've found nothing
2. Custom Eslint rule (looks like overhead solution)
3. Use another static analyzer tool such as sonar qube, etc.

Comment: What about using a Redux to store the tableIds in the global state. Then, before rendering a new table, you can check if the tableId already exists ?

Comment: if you don't use table id for any dom operation pass UUID. and if you use table id in dom operation then maintain all table id in context or in redux and check new table id is exist in useEffect

Comment: I think this might be possible in some _very_ limited way with static analyzer if someone tried. But even still this might have some issues: what if `tableId` is passed as variable? What if the `tableId` is dynamically generated? What if `tableId` includes variable? Altough these situations might be ignored probably the most problematic would be having two tables with same id inside a condition. In this case won't have multiple tables with same id at runtime, but one at a time, still the analyzer might not get that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, i use any unique string generator, and you passed it into your id.
https://github.com/ai/nanoid

`const Table1 = () => <Table tableId={nanoid()}/>`

If it is in loop, try not to use this. it need stable ID

Comment: This should work, but I need my own created ids with human-readable names, like <tableName>-id